# bash built in function bash source code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, built-in

How to find source of a built in bash function?

I know that it is a function:

```
$type -t MY_APP
function
```

I see it's code:

```
type MY_APP
code
```

The questions are:

1. Where is it stored?
2. How can I modify it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
# Turn on debug
$ shopt -s extdebug

# Print out the function's name, line number and file where it was sourced from
$ declare -F my_function
my_function 46 /home/dogbane/.bash/.bash_functions

# Turn off debug
shopt -u extdebug
```

To edit the function, open the file containing the function definition (that you found from above). Edit the function and save the file. Then source it into your shell, like this:

```
$ . /path/to/function_file
```

Comment: it works! I tried declare -F my_function, but it prints only the function name without the debug function. Thanks for a good advice.

Comment: +1 I've never used `extdebug`, so didn't know there was a way to see the file a function was sourced from. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are typically stored in the `.bashrc` file (or in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which also exists as just `/etc/bashrc` on some systems). [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/49292/113093) from SuperUser has some good details on what a `.bashrc` file is. Similarly, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function) on the Unix & Linux site details when it's best to alias, when to script, and when to write a function.

Comment: The linked topic is interesting. I searched in .bashrc and .bashprofile, the defined function was in other place. The @dogbane 's answer helped me.